# Setting up ADAL in Visual Studio 2010 legacy app for JWT (JSON Web Token)

Tags: json, visual-studio-2010, jwt, adal

I need to use JSON Web Tokens (JWT) in a legacy application built in Visual Studio 2010, and coded in Visual Basic ... but I have no idea of how to add the required ADAL component to Visual Studio 2010 so that I can access the functionality ... can somebody please explain how to set up ADAL so that it is accessible from the legacy application?

Answer (score 0):

ADAL is not strictly required for working with JWTs. In any case: VS2010 came with .NET 4.0 - and there's only one version of ADAL that can work with that: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/1.0.5.
Although you can still use it, please be advised that the version 1.x is no longer supported at this point.